# How can I prove that $X$ is numerable?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $Y$ be numerable. Assume that $f:X\to Y$ is surjection such that for each $y\in Y$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is numerable.

How can I prove that $X$ is numerable?

Comment: By numerable, do you mean countable?

Comment: X is the domain of f so X $\subset \cup_{y\in Y}f^{-1}y$.  As Y is countable/numerable then the union is a countable/numerable of countable sets, and is countable.  So X is a subset of a countable set.  And is therefore countable.

Comment: **Hint:** You'll need at least countable choice.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $X = \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y)$. What do you know about countable unions of countable sets?